# Where can I configure user and admin email message in Ubercart cart module?

Tags: 7, ubercart

Where can I configure user and admin email message in Ubercart cart module in Drupal 7?

I want to change the email body of user notification email and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> sites/all/module/ubercart/uc_order/templates/

than select *file user* or *admin*